# How to get a 3D plot of from the the solutions of function

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have the following equation:

```
(1 - x)^2 + T^2/((f[x] - L)*(f[x] - L - 2*T))*(P/(N-R+S)) == 0

f[x] = (x*r*(T + L) - T)/((x*r) - 1)
```

`P, (N-R+S), T, L` and `r` are all constants in the following intervals

```
P ∈ {10,50}, (N-R+S) ∈ {20,90}, T = 12, L ∈ {2, 10}
```

I would like have 3D plot from the solution for the x when say both P and L changes within the above intervals.

is there any way to do this?

Comment: There is a missing parenthesis in your code; please correct it.

Comment: Are you planning to include definitions for `f` and `T`?

Comment: f[x]=(x*a(T+L)-T)/(x*a-1), a is constant value in the interval [0,1]. L,T and A are constant values. i would like to see how the solution for x changes with respect to different parameters. x is also can only get values between [0, 1]. I hope that answers your questions

Comment: sorry for the missing parenthesis, just corrected it.

Comment: "xa" means x*a and a=A?

Comment: I edited the problem, hopefully it is now is clear.

Comment: mgamer, no a is not equal to A. sorry for the confusion. I rewrote the problem with new parameters.

Comment: You also need to know that using a capital letter as the first character of a symbol is a bad practice, because the resulting symbol may conflict with a Mathematica function, like `N`.

Comment: Yes thanks, I'll use another symbol. but first i need to know how to get the graph (if possible).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

```
t = 12;
r = 2;
nrs = 40;
f[x_] := (x*r*(t + l) - t)/((x*r) - 1)
eq = (1 - x)^2 + t^2/((f[x] - l)*(f[x] - l - 2*t))*(p/(nrs)) == 0
Plot3D[x /. Solve[eq, x], {p, 10, 50}, {l, 2, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! now i have two more questions. 1. the acceptable x is between [0, 1], how can i get rid of the top surface?

Comment: 2. I have a cost function which is a function of x, can I also plot a 3d graph to see how cost changes with respect to L and p ? i.e. using the solution of x as input for the cost fucntion.

Comment: Thanks bellisarius! I try with different values and the bottom graph is the one i need to report on. I couldnt remove the one on top. any suggestion?